# TapClick and TapView on one go

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have gone through all the post in every forum, but wasn't successful in digging. I tried to implement Junit automation test case for my project but am struck at a particular point. Could you please give me an idea or a template how to continue, here is the customized and short scenario.

I have an `Activity` which has a button, when i click on the button, a popup appears. I have an `EditText` and a button in the popup, I need to tap the `EditText` - set a value to it and then click on button.

My solution so far: I am able to click on the button and popup appears, then i am tapping on `EditText`, which is hinting with an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the painful world of Android testing!

I would recommend you using [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) instead of jUnit for this kind of tests.

Comment: Thank you, Will start having my hands on Robotium, for any help - will get back ..